# Write on multiple lines simultaneously using stdout

Tags: python, multithreading

So as the title says, I'm wondering how to write on multiple lines at the same time, the reason that I want todo this is because I'm using multithreading, and want each thread to display their progress without it printing everything on the same line

Right now I'm using this function to write to the terminal.

```
def write( text ):
    sys.stdout.write( "\r" + text )
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm not very experienced with python, so if you've got a solution, then please explain it so that a total noob like me can understand :P

Comment: I would like to know this too, for the same reason, I want to have progress bars on 10 lines, one each for my threads, and update them each time the process in each thread finishes. An example of - print on line x - would be useful. Is that what you are after ? did you figure it out ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a simple synchronization mechanism, like a [`Lock`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects), to prevent two threads writing to standard output concurrently:

```
from threading import Lock
writelock = Lock()

def write( text ):
    writelock.acquire()
    sys.stdout.write( "\r" + text )
    sys.stdout.flush()
    writelock.release()
```

Comment: I don't think that is what the OP is asking for - but that is very useful.